# Creating soap request with suds

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, suds

I need some help with suds request in python.

Generated XML request looks like this

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <m:ExternalApiHeader xmlns:m="http://www.GlobalBettingExchange.com/ExternalAPI/" version="" languageCode="" username="" password="" applicationIdentifier=""/>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <m:GetEventSubTreeWithSelections xmlns:m="http://www.GlobalBettingExchange.com/ExternalAPI/">
        <m:getEventSubTreeWithSelectionsRequest WantPlayMarkets="true">
            <m:EventClassifierIds>2147483647</m:EventClassifierIds>
        </m:getEventSubTreeWithSelectionsRequest>
    </m:GetEventSubTreeWithSelections>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I have created python script and the only thing I can't figure out how to pass the value EventClassifierIds, which is 2147483647

```
import suds
url = 'http://api.betdaq.com/v2.0/API.wsdl'
client = suds.client.Client(url)

#prepare headers
token=client.factory.create('ExternalApiHeader')
token._version='2'
token._languageCode='en'
token._username=''
token._password=''
client.set_options(soapheaders=token)

#reguest
result = client.service.GetEventSubTreeWithSelections('false')
print result
```

Comment: What does the WDSL says about the GetEventSubTreeWithSelections method ?

Comment: language : String(2)
[variable]
handle : long <Event>
[optionally]
wantPlayMarkets : Boolean
Flag indicating whether information about play markets or real markets should be returned. Values are true: only information about play markets is to be returned and false: only information about real markets should be returned. If not specified a value of false is assumed

Comment: <xs:complexType name="GetEventSubTreeWithSelectionsRequest">
<xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="EventClassifierIds" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="WantPlayMarkets" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>

Comment: And have you tried passing `EventClassifierIds` ? `client.service.GetEventSubTreeWithSelections(EventClassifierIds=2147483647)` ?

Comment: It is not working. I recived: xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:2421:2: unclosed token

Comment: In PHP this request looks like this. $result = $BDSoapClient->GetEventSubTreeWithSelections(array('getEventSubTreeWithSelectionsRequest'=>array('WantPlayMarkets'=>false,'EventClassifierIds'=>100003)));

Comment: hey. what kind of average times do you get for get prices and place bet ?